# Один результат на букву DLE?

Tags: php, dle

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать один результат на букву в /catalog/L/. Сейчас выводятся все новости на букву и идет дубликат
Я допустим добавил 4 трека.

Linkin Park - 1
Linkin Park - 2
Linkin Park - 3
Leone - 4

Но при переходе на страницу site.ru/catalog/L/. Выходят все 4 новости, а как сделать что было. Т.е шло объединение?

Linkin Park 
Leone 
А если взять ссылку http://topmuzon.com/singer/la-kamila/

То в каталоге он один. Вот другой пример http://kztune.com/singers/

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в вашем случае будет полезен алгоритм [Левенштейна](https://ru.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), на php есть [встроенная](https://php.ru/manual/function.levenshtein.html) функция.
Если будут вопросы по использованию, задайте. Обратите внимание, работает это не быстро, поэтому разумно кешировать результат.
Так же полезно посмотреть на встроенные функции php: similar_text, soundex, metaphone.